# I was just making a simple kivy app but then I crash into this error so how should I fix it, Even looked up tutorials but nothing helpful

Tags: python, kivy, builder

So here it goes

Error message:

`kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <Spamming>`

Main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
import time
import pyautogui


Builder.load_file('SpamBot.kv')


class Spamming(Widget):
    pass


class SpamBotByOmkarApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SpamBotByOmkarApp().run()
```

and the SpamBot.kv file:

```
Spamming:

<Spamming>:
    TextInput:
        id: "message"
        width: "100dp"
```

Please help cuz I have to show it to my professor in a week  :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your `kv` file with `Builder.load_file('SpamBot.kv')`which use `Spamming` but you create `Spamming`after the call so... it doesn't know what is `Spamming`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
import time
import pyautogui


class Spamming(Widget):
    pass


class SpamBotByOmkarApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('SpamBot.kv')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SpamBotByOmkarApp().run()
```

PS: **I was just making a simple kivy app but then I crash into this error so how should I fix it, Even looked up tutorials but nothing helpful** , 28 words to say nothing useful, be more precise or nobody will help you. **kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class XXXXX** would have been better.